# Problem Reindexing Catalog Url

Tags: indexing

I am trying to reindex my magento installation but I get this error when I run:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size' in /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#5 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#6 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#7 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(317): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('core_url_rewrit...', Array, Array)
#8 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(366): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveRewrite(Array, Object(Varien_Object))
#9 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(568): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('4')
#11 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('4')
#12 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#13 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#14 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size' in /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#4 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#5 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `core_ur...', Array)
#6 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(317): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('core_url_rewrit...', Array, Array)
#7 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(366): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveRewrite(Array, Object(Varien_Object))
#8 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(568): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Varien_Object))
#9 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('4')
#10 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('4')
#11 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#12 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#13 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /srv/www/htdocs/MascagniB2B/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

What should I do to solve this "The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size" problem?

The problem came out after I changed my import script adding:

```
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL));
$processes->walk('save');

...import...

$processes->walk('reindexAll');
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon using the Google I came accross [this post](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/) which seems to provide a solution by increasing the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in your servers `my.cnf`.

If you don't have access to that file it might help to just truncate the `core_url_rewrite` tabel since it can grow pretty big. I've seen tables with close to 500.000 rows, locking all of these might cause an issue with InnoDB.

*Note that truncating the table will delete all old and custom redirects tho and please try this on a dev environment first and make backups. Although the table should rebuild itself after reindexing there might be issues.*

Comment: Increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 50MB worked! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I truncated table `core_url_rewrite` and still got the same issue.

So, I accessed server via `ssh` with PuTTY and then opened my `/etc/my.cnf` file and increased the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from 2 to 64MB.

Try this one it should work fine.